# Retrieving the value of the datatable row object before editing it

Tags: jsf

i have a dataTble cotaining object of type Action , the user can choose ana action to modify it so i want to retrieve the old action before modifying it so i tried the onStart attribute to do it  but i get this error:

```
oct. 15, 2012 11:42:12 AM 
 com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit 
 Grave: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /manageProjectTestsPage.xhtml @342,417       
 onstart="#{projectTestManagementMB.initOldAction}": Property 'initOldAction' not found 
 on type tn.talan.testFramework.managedBean.ProjectTestManagementMB
```

here's the code :

```
    public String initOldAction(){
     String index=(String)    

     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
     getRequestParameterMap().get("index");
 System.out.println("index "+index);

  oldSelectedAction =testActionList.get(Integer.parseInt(index));
  return null;

}
```

xhtml:

```
 <p:column headerText="Options">  

     <p:commandLink id="modifyManualActionBtn" style="margin-right:5px"     onstart="# 
     {projectTestManagementMB.initOldAction}"  actionListener="#
      {projectTestManagementMB.verifyTestDisponibilityActionModifying}"  
      title="modify" update=":form:growl :form:testTabView:confirmModifyActionDialog 
      :form:testTabView:addModifyActionDlg" disabled="#
       {projectTestManagementMB.modifyBtnFlag}">
       <h:graphicImage value="../images/cssImg/modify_icon.png" heigth="13"width="17"/>
       <f:param name="index" value="#{rowIndex}" />
      </p:commandLink>
  ....
```

So how to use the onstart attribute to retrieve the old action value before executing the actionListener `actionListener="#
          {projectTestManagementMB.verifyTestDisponibilityActionModifying}"`
And if i can not use it ,Is there another solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are retrieving this error because the `onstart` attribute is a value attribute that should be set to a Javascript expression to execute before the ajax request begins.  You can use an EL expression here, however it is not like `actionListener` which expects a method expression.

By not having the parenthesis in the EL expression for `onstart`, JSF assumes this a call to a Managed Property rather than a method.  Try this instead:

```
onstart="#{projectTestManagementMB.initOldAction()}"
```

This isn't your actual problem however as your method `initOldAction()` doesn't return a String containing a Javascript expression.  I don't think this attribute does what you think it does, it is just a client side callback.